# Possible real life applications for producing artificial aurora?

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, weather

I'm writing a hard sci-fi novel and I am trying to create both metaphorical and literal scenic atmospheric ambiance by having artificial auroras being easy to produce in the night sky. Any clue as to what realistic possible, real life applications this might have to have a justification within a plot?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take a good read at our [help] to better understand our scope. Also, please pick one between science based and hard science: those two tags are mutually exclusive

Comment: Does the Aurora have to be a goal, or can it be a side effect?

Answer (score 2):

### Why, to study them of course...

Auroras represent some pretty violent physics in action in the upper atmosphere. They're the visible evidence of the Sun trying to beat Earth's protective magnetosphere half to death! But natural weather (space or otherwise) tends to make repeatable experiments rather... difficult. The solution? Replicate the conditions yourself!

There's some pretty complex physics going on up there behind the scenes, but the US Air Force Research Laboratory was interested enough that they [***actually funded the creation an artificial aurora and published a paper on it!***](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fspas.2019.00014/full) (apparently people have been doing this kind of stuff since the 80's - see Section 3 of the paper)

Now, I'm not going to claim to understand half of what they talk about in that paper or what they were actually trying to do, but the short and curly is: *There are real people who are really making artificial auroras in real life!*

Answer (score 1):

*(please remove the hard-science tag.. the method to create the Aurora is not your question, you want to know why it would be done, finding a "justification" for activity is no hard science imho)*

**Artificial aurora can brighten up the sky at night**

On planet Earth, Aurora is relatively rare and dim, it is caused by solar flares ionizing the upper atmosphere. When you can ionize artifically, the Aurora could be  made brighter, maybe permanent.

A justification may be economic reasons.. suppose your planet has a thriving economy, northern and southern countries have advanced industry and technology, able to create  their artificial Aurora. Their 24/7 economy may profit from having prolongued light in winter time.

Answer (score 0):

**Celebration!**

[image: klieg lights and fireworks]

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fireworks_and_klieg_lights_frame_the_Grand_Peterhof_Palace.jpg

People love huge glowy stuff in the sky!  Artifical auroras would be better than fireworks and klieg lights.   Heck, have all three!   Your people make auroras to celebrate!

Comment: Or massive commerial advertisement/political propaganda. Nothing beats a giant "GME to the MOOOOOON" or "Long live the Great Leader" in the night sky for psychological impact